# Numerical Algebraic geometry in the finite fields

Tags: finite-field

Does the numerical algebraic geometry method work in the finite fields?
I am working on this method to find a solution for a low-degree proximity testing problem.

Would you please guide me how they work in the finite fields?

> **Clarification:** Consider the $d$ low-degree proximity testing problem for Reed Solomon codes (RPT). Informally, we can define it as below:

The RPT problem assumes a verifier has oracle access to $f$ (as the evaluation of some points by calculating the RS code i.e it is a polynomial in the finite field) and to auxiliary information like a PCP (Polynomially Checkable Proof) of Proximity (PCPP) or an IOP (Interactive Oracle Proof) of proximity (IOPP); the verifier’s task is to distinguish with high probability and with a small number of queries to $f$ and the auxiliary PCPP/IOPP oracle(s), between the cases:

- that $f$ is a codeword of $RS[F,S,\rho]$; and the case that
- $f$ is $δ-$far from all codewords of $ RS[F,S,\rho]$ in relative Hamming distance.

The existing solutions such as [LINK](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwinn8jR6dreAhXB-aQKHeRmDYIQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Feccc.weizmann.ac.il%2Freport%2F2017%2F134%2Frevision%2F1%2Fdownload%2F&usg=AOvVaw2YcawBRPs0h77N4NY2aapp) used some techniques including *Fast Fourier Transform* and also you can find more information about *IOP*.

Comment: Would you please define give references for "numerical algebraic geometry"?

Comment: Will you define "proximity test"?

Comment: @kodlu: Yes of course. Please take a look on "What is Numerical Algebraic Geometry?" by  Jonathan D. Hauenstein et al.

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych: Precisely, I am trying to find low-degree proximity testing problem for Reed Solomon codes (RPT). Informally, we can define it as: The RPT problem assumes a verifier has oracle access to f, and to auxiliary information like a PCP of Proximity (PCPP) or an IOP of proximity (IOPP); the verifier’s task is to distinguish with high probability and with a small number of queries to f and the auxiliary PCPP/IOPP oracle(s), between the case that f is a codeword of RS[F,S,ρ] and the case that f∈(0,1) is δ-far from  all codewords of RS[F,S,ρ] in relative Hamming distance.

Comment: @Niloofar, OK, but all this should be in the question statement, in my opinion.

Comment: please fix any errors in my edit. the last statement about $f$ looks problematic.

Comment: @kodlu, Thank you so much. It becomes so better than before. I hope it is easy to follow.

Comment: Well $f\in (0,1)$ makes no sense to me, I am afraid.